# KeyCloak Spring Boot - Add custom code on auth success

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am using KeyCloak integration with Spring Boot as in [this](https://dzone.com/articles/secure-spring-boot-application-with-keycloak) guide. I have my security config like below:

```
class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

I want to add some custom code for `onAuthenticationSuccess` before KeyCloak redirects me to the actual resource. I tried implementing a custom class with `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and do `formLogin().successHandler(...)`. This didn't work. How can I get this working??

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? Is this a new project? If so, I'd recommend not using `keycloak-spring-boot-starter`, and using Spring Security 5.5 with built-in support for oauth2 client. See [spring-security-keycloak-demo](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-security-keycloak-demo) for a sample project to get started. If you're looking to use OAuth2 to login, you need to use something like `.oauth2Login((oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login.successHandler(...))` instead of `.formLogin(...)`.

Comment: Just trying to understand why not the keycloak starter? Can you elaborate a little??

Comment: Sure. 1) keycloak starter is not maintained by the Spring Security community, and is therefore a keycloak-specific implementation, so you can't really get much help from the spring security community, 2) the spring security adapter pins an old version of spring security (latest pins to 5.2.9, but latest 5.2.x is 5.2.12) so you may not get the latest security patches, and 3) much/all of its functionality seems subsumed by later versions of spring security. Therefore, I would just recommend using spring security. Of course, it's your choice, and there may be good reasons for using keycloak.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg how do you generate a JWT token in either of the 2 libraries?

Comment: [Here's an example of how generate JWTs using Nimbus](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/java/example/web/TokenController.java) in the spring-security-samples project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still prefer to use Spring Boot KeyCloak, something like this will work.

```
public class KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler extends KeycloakAuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    public KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler fallback) {
        super(fallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            AccessToken token = ((KeycloakPrincipal<?>) authentication.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
        }
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

And in your security config or similar file that extends `KeyCloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` do the following:

```
@Bean
@Override
protected KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
    filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
    return filter;
}


@NotNull
@Bean
public KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot! Thank you